# How to align input fields in a modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that is 800px wide. It has two columns equal size. the input fields on the left column are lining up ok. the input fields on the right are not. I cannot figure out how to get both sides lined up correctly. i made a plunkr but it doesnt show the left side to be aligned. It is aligned in my modal though. The input fields on the right side need to be aligned on the right side of the modal. and if possible is there a way to make the select boxes the same same height as the input fields? 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfoGHgf8DmQY43WSpND1?p=preview)

```
@*<style>form {display: table; } p {display: table-row;}label {display: table-cell;} input {display: table-cell;}
        label, input {
            margin: 5px 0px;
        }
    </style>*@
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class=" modal-dialog  modal-editJob vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">View / Edit Job</h4>
                    <h3 style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">{{currentItem.JobName}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#Cover" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cover</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Detail" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Detail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Items" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!--Cover Content-->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Cover">
                            <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
                                <form ng-submit="submitJob()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Number:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobNumber" type="text">
                                                <label>Status:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <select ng-model="currentItem.Status">
                                                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                                    <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
                                                    <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Name:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Status:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <select ng-model="currentItem.Status">
                                                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                                    <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
                                                    <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Hide:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobHidden" type="checkbox">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Address:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobAddress" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>City</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobCity" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>State</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobState" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Zipcode</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.JobZipcode" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>TESPM:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.TESPM" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>TESPM:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <select ng-options="employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName as employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName for employee in employeeArray | filter:{EmployeeIsPM : true}" ng-model="currentItem.TESPM">
                                                    <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Original&nbsp;Contract:&nbsp;$</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.OriginalContract" type="text" format="number">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Total&nbsp;CO&nbsp;$</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.TotalCO" type="text" format="number">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Revised&nbsp;Contract&nbsp;$</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.RevisedContract" type="text" format="number">
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Customer&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerName" ng-click="EditJobCustomerModal(currentItem.CustomerId)" type="text" />
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Address:&nbsp;</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerAddress" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>City</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerCity" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>State</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerState" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Zipcode</label>
                                                <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerZipcode" type="text">
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset><br />
                                    <input style="margin-right:20px" ng-click="printEditJobModal(currentItem)" type="button" value="Print" go-click="#" />
                                    <input style="float:right" ng-click="updateJob(currentItem)" type="button" value="Update" go-click="#" />
                                    <input style="float:right; margin-right:20px" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" go-click="#" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="Detail">...</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="Items">...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: well, for starters you don't have enough space. See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qhu3wm1j/ . You should give a class to that first row line, then give a fixed width to labels and a fixed width to all elements in that first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving the `input` elements random inline `margin-left`s, you should add a fixed width to the `label`s.

```
.inline-fields label {
    ...
    width: 80px; /* Choose the width that best fits your needs */
    ...
}
```